# Combinatorics: Prove the number of matches in a Singles Tournament

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I was working my way through some problems in [Discrete Maths by Rosen](http://www.flipkart.com/discrete-mathematics-its-applications-combinatorics-graph-theory-english-7th/p/itmdwxxszhczjrnf), when I came across the following question:

> There are *x* players in a singles badminton tournament
>
> **Show that there are *x-1* matches played in the tournament**

***My question:***

How can I prove it ?

Comment: How is it obvious?

Comment: Is there more to the question?

Comment: No , @Eleven-Eleven , there is nothing more to the question

Comment: Hi , @TheChaz2.0 , by obvious , I meant the answer that nathey has given :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every match eliminates a single player. So if there's only one champion when all is finished, $x-1$ matches will be played.